# Google Forms Regex "Doesn't Match" Between Specific Range Doesn't Work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need help regarding using Regex as data validation in a short-answer question in Google Forms. According to my understanding, if I use this expression:

`"Doesn't Match"` + `[a-zA-Z]{1,}|[0-9]{1,15}|[0-9]{17,140}`

I should still be able to fill the answer with 16 digits of numbers. However, I was unable to input any digits of number at all. Does anyone have any solution for this?

As a side note, I can't use "Matches" nor "Contains" because I have to link it to Google Spreadsheet for "unique value" data validation as well and Google Forms doesn't support multiple data validations. Here's my current script:

```
//Still needs much better solution, but this will do for now
function checkNIK(){
  //Get current form
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  //Open spreadsheet containing NIK
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(<id>);
  
  //Get sheet
  var responses = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');

  //Get list of all NIK in column F, which contains a few hundreds 16-digits numbers.
  var disallowedArray = responses.getRange('F:F').getValues();
  
  //Clean NIK list
  disallowedArray = disallowedArray.filter(item => item != ''); //Empty cells
  disallowedArray = disallowedArray.filter(item => item != 'NIK'); //Cell named "NIK"

  //Transform NIK list array into a single string
  var disallowedString = disallowedArray.join("|");

  //Append additional expressions
  //Doesn't work, adding "|[0-9]{17,140}" makes the form unable to accept 16 digits number anymore
  disallowedString = disallowedString.concat('|[a-zA-Z\\s]{1,}|[0-9]{1,15}|[0-9]{17,140}');

  //Print regex just to make sure
  //console.log(disallowedString);

  //Select the question you want to update
  var item = form.getItemById(<id>).asTextItem();

  //Create validation rule
  var validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('Wrong or duplicate NIK.')
  .requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(disallowedString)
  .build();

  item.setValidation(validation);
}
```

Let me know if there's something I did wrong, both on-topic and off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for replying only one year later. The problem was on my side, not regex. After countless experiments, I was able to get the correct regex and condition to only accept precisely 16 numbers.

The condition that I used was
`.requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(allowedString)`.
This condition was what made this seemingly simple problem very hard to accomplish in Google Forms.

As for the regex itself:
`[a-zA-Z\\s]{1,}|[0-9a-zA-Z\\s]{1,15}|[0-9a-zA-Z\\s]{17,140}$`

Basically, it disallows anything that is not 16 characters in length. It also disallows any letter and special symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Though I cannot provide a reasoning why you encountered such error. I found a workaround for you to be able to input 16 digits of numbers.

I just changed the order of the expression then test if it will work:

```
Regex: [0-9]{17,140}|[0-9]{1,15}
```

[image]

**Input: 15 digits**

[image]

**Input: 16 digits**

[image]

**Input: 17 digits**

[image]

Comment: Oh my, it actually worked! I don't have any explanation for this either other than bug. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your need to enclose the regular expression in brackets.

```
([a-zA-Z]{1,}|[0-9]{1,15}|[0-9]{17,140})
```

Comment: Now, I'm confused. If what you said is true, then what's the difference with using "doesn't contain" in this context?

Comment: @Athryan I am sorry that my previous answer was wrong. I have corrected it.